# Need help with converting $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+2)^2}$ to partial fractions

Tags: partial-fractions

So far I have my working ...

[image]

I think I got wrong ... since after checking with http://calc101.com/webMathematica/partial-fractions.jsp#topdoit

$A = \frac{1}{9}$

$B = - \frac{1}{9}$

$C = - \frac{1}{3}$

Is there a better way to do this than simultaneous equations? Or any tips on how solving such problems ... in a recent exam, I find myself getting a ton of simultaneous equations like below (maybe I need to see "patterns" that make my lefe easier) and likely made careless mistakes within them

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48051/the-existence-of-partial-fraction-decompositions/63308#63308) for a closed formula for partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: $(2)-(1)$ should be $0=3A+C$ instead of $0=3A-C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get to the line with

$$1 = A(x+2)^2+ B(x-1)(x+2) + C(x-1)$$

You can try plugging in x values that simplify things a bunch to solve for the variables.  For example, plugging in $x = 1$ or $x = -2$ leaves only one variable to solve for.  This is not always possible, but it's a lot simpler than looking at the $x^2$ term and so on, when it is possible.

Plug in $x = -2$ and you get $1 = C(-3)$, so $C = -\frac{1}{3}$.  Plug in $x = 1$ and you get $1 = 9A$, so $A = \frac{1}{9}$.  Now, you know $A$ and $C$, so you can plug in any other value to get $B$, say, $x = 0$.  That gives

$$1 = \frac{1}{9} \cdot 4 - 2B + \frac{1}{3}$$

which gives $B = -\frac{1}{9}$.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, there is a sign error is in the calculation  of $\:(2)-(1)\:.\:$ As for "better ways" here are a couple remarks. First, eliminate easy things first. Above you have $A + B = 0,\:$ so $B = -A$. Eliminating $B$ yields $\:3\:A + C = 0,\ $ $6\:A-C = 1,\:$ which summed, yields $\:9\:A = 1\:.\:$ Now back-substituting yields $B,C\:.$ Notice how much easier the elimination is using this ordering strategy.

Second, there are well-known tricks that exploit the special structure enjoyed by systems of linear equations that arise from partial fraction decompositions, e.g. see [Heaviside's cover-up method.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) Additionally see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23484/help-solving-int-frac8x415x316x222x4xx12x22dx/23498#23498) which discusses nonlinear generalizations of this method.