# Partial fraction decomposition and polynomials?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185264/the-logic-behind-partial-fraction-decomposition/185273?noredirect=1#comment1873973_185273) gives a really great explanation of why partial fraction decomposition works. However, the explanation implies that rational functions can be decomposed into a sum of fractions *plus a polynomial*. Yet, when decomposing rational functions we don't seem to account for the potential polynomial term. Why?

Comment: @TedShifrin Of course, totally forgot about that. Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure we do, if the degree of the numerator is at least the degree of the denominator. We do long division first to recover the polynomial part.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!