# Identity problem with polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n>1$, having n different real roots $x_{1},\dots 
 ,x_n$ and a coefficient $a_n$ with $x^n$ and let $Q$ be a polynomial of degree not greater than $n-1$. Prove that
$$ \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{Q(x_k)}{P'(x_k)(x-x_k)}$$ for $ x \in R$, $x\notin$ {$x_1, \dots, x_n$}.

I have proved that $$P'(x_k)=a_n \prod_{j\not=k}(x_j - x_k)$$ but with that, I haven't got anything.

Comment: @dxiv It helps, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P(x)$ has the form $P(x)=A(x-x_1)\dots (x-x_n)$, then $\dfrac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ can be expressed in partial fractions whose existence can be seen in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48051/691503), for example. So we have the following form $\displaystyle\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{(x-x_k)}$, then we multiply both members by $(x-x_j)$,
$$
\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \cdot (x-x_j)= \sum_{k\neq j} \frac{a_k}{(x-x_k)}\cdot (x-x_j)+a_j
$$
Now we do $x\to x_j$ and get
$$
\lim_{x\to x_j}\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \cdot (x-x_j)=a_j
$$
Hence
$$
a_j=\lim_{x\to x_j}\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} \cdot (x-x_j)=\lim_{x\to x_j}\left(\frac{x-x_j}{P(x)-P(x_j)}\right)Q(x)=\frac{Q(x_j)}{P'(x_j)},\quad \forall j=1,2,\dots,n.
$$

Which concludes that:
$$
\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{(x-x_k)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{Q(x_k)}{P'(x_k)(x-x_k)}
$$

Comment: "*Just take the form*" $\;-\;$ You have to prove that such form exists in the first place.

Comment: @dxiv I think the real question of the MO, is the particular form that the partial fraction decomposition has, not its existence. I look forward to some feedback from the MO.

Comment: @Zaragosa I understand your proof, but I don't know how to prove first line in the proof (existence of such a form). I will appreciate any help with that.

Comment: @ns123 I understand, so it was my fault for misunderstanding your question. dxiv put a link that can help you on that part as well.

Comment: @Zaragosa Now I understand. Thank you :)